# How to show each nested list in a seperate column, preferrably while using CSS Grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some nested lists. Some go as deep as 4-5 level deep. For example:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="is-parent">parent</span>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="no-child">child</li>
            <li class="no-child">child</li>
            <li class="no-child">child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>some child</li>
    <li>another child</li>
<ul>
```

This list is displayed in a css grid column, the first one to be specific. I have set the columns using

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
```

When I click on parent, I want the nested `<ul>` to display on the next column.
What is the best way to do that using vanila JavaScript?

Something like the example here: https://mynameistechno.github.io/finderjs/#examples

But without the use of a library or plugin.

Comment: jQuery *is* a library, but even with jQuery you'll write a fairly substantial set of functions to do that. You'll need to grab the list items and move them to a new DOM location, then keep track of what's showing and what's not. It'll get a bit twisty. The point is that your question is very broad and you'll need to give it a go and ask something more specific. Be sure to not confuse folks by tagging jQuery and then disallowing it.

Comment: My mistake. Just removed the tag

Comment: I'd have to search for one just as you will. JavaScript DOM manipulation is well-covered on the web. jQuery makes life *much* easier for that, though.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="is-parent">parent</span>
    <ul class="children hide">
        <li class="no-child">child</li>
        <li class="no-child">child</li>
        <li class="no-child">child</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>some child</li>
  <li>another child</li>
<ul>
```

CSS

```
 ul {
     grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
 }
 .hide {
     display: none;
 }
```

JS

```
document.querySelectorAll('is-parent').forEach(node => 
    node.parentNode.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
        let cl = ev.currentTarget.querySelector('ul').classList
        cl.contains('hide') ? cl.remove('hide') : cl.add('hide')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to do this without the jQuery library.

But here I wrote an example using only javascript.

The idea is when you click on `is-parent` you `clone` the `Children` and append to `container`.

You could build on this example.

I hop this help you somehow

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("is-parent");
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
function bind(items){
new Array(items).forEach(function(item, index){
  item = item[0]
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var children= [].filter.call(item.parentElement.childNodes, function(node) {
    return node.className == "children"
   })[0];
   var i= children.cloneNode(true);
   container.appendChild(i);
   i.style.display = "block";
   
   i.className = index;
  });
});
}
bind(x);
```

```css
.children{
display:none;
}

ul{
pointer:default;
}

div{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="is-parent">parent</span>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="no-child">child</li>
            <li class="no-child">child</li>
            <li class="no-child">child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>some child</li>
    <li>another child</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: I write to fast sometime and forget to check what i wrote. actually im really bad at writing :)  Appreciate your help